# NAME_MAX is not 255 in my case

Tags: configuration, centos

When I've tested in Centos on Docker(centos:latest), it was not 255.

```
# getconf NAME_MAX /
242
```

But it's defined in `limits.h` correctly

```
# cat /usr/include/linux/limits.h | grep NAME_MAX
#define NAME_MAX         255    /* # chars in a file name */
```

What is problem with me and what should check more?

Comment: You grepped for NAME_MAX, but a number came out?

Comment: @holygeek Sorry. Fixed it!